# Attach Sharepoint file in the Microsoft Teams webhook message

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I have a file that is on Sharepoint for the Team and in the folder corresponding to my channel in Microsoft Teams.

E.g. Team `Banana` channel `ripe`, so my file is in `https://whatever.sharepoint.com/Banana/ripe`

I want to share this file to the channel with a message programmatically to get this result:

[image: screenshot]

I got the above message in the teams client by going to `Files` tab, clicking on file and then `Start conversation`.

I want to share this file using a webhook.

Unfortunately i can't find anything in regards to `MessageCard` payloads that the webhook seems to use that would allow me to do the above.

I tried adding `attachments` part of the bot reference to the message like so but had no success:

```
POST https://outlook.office.com/webhook/whateverelsehere HTTP/1.1
Host: outlook.office.com
Content: application/json
Content-Length: 401

{
  "@type": "MessageCard",
  "text":"This is a message3",
  "attachments": [{
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.file.info",
    "contentUrl": "https://wherever.sharepoint.com/sites/feed-support/Banana/ripe/test.txt",
    "name": "text.txt",
    "content": {
      "uniqueId": "df90889f-e8a7-452a-8795-972be16fac6f",
      "fileType": "txt",
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to send files using webhooks. Files support in webhook is something we are working on but we do not have an ETA for it. As of now, the only way of sending files is using Bots.

Comment: Ok, what is the payload to send a file as a bot so it looks like this in the team channel, not to an individual user:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU8bC.png

Comment: Please go through [Send and receive files through Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=dotnet).

Comment: of course i have been through this article. it is utterly useless. I need to ping a USER to upload a file and user has to click 'OK upload the file'. This is NOT what i need. I need fully automatic submission of logs to a channel.

Comment: I found how to upload files to the right Sharepoint in Teams, i even found a way to construct the URL so i can add a button to the message and file opens for the user in the browser, all i need is that 'conversation about a file' functionality

Comment: Do you want to send the files in channel? Sending files is currently supported only in personal scope.

Comment: see my screenshot in the question. As a user i can do the above. i want to do the SAME in code.
Which is I add a file on Sharepoint, and add a message to the chat.

Comment: Sending files inside a teams channel using teams SDK is currently not supported. The only to do this is by using the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=dotnet#using-the-microsoft-graph-apis)